# Trying to get json data to be parsed into an SQL server

Tags: python, mysql, json

By using python, I have been trying to get data from an online API and parsing it into a MySQL server.  However, I keep running into different errors. One the errors has been

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'get' File "C:\Users\bazoo\ShortPy\ShortPy.py", line 19, in <module> title=comic.get("title")"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import Connection, Cursor 
import requests
import sqlite3
import json
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import MySQLdb
import mysql.connector
import pymysql
from requests.models import Response

response_API= requests.get('https://api.shortboxed.com/comics/v1/new')
data=response_API.json()
comics_in_box=json.dumps(data)
conn = pymysql.connect(host ="", user ="", password = "", db ="")
cursor=conn.cursor()

for comic in comics_in_box:
    title=comic.get("title")
    publisher=comic.get("publisher")
    price=comic.get("price")
    diamond_id=comic.get("diamond_id")
    cursor.execute("insert into Shortbox (title, publisher, price, diamond_id) value (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (title, publisher, price, diamond_id))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
  File "C:\Users\bazoo\ShortPy\ShortPy.py", line 19, in <module>
    title=comic.get("title")

Comment: yea, json.dumps makes a string out of an object so you just probably need to not do `comics_in_box=json.dumps(data)` and say `comics_in_box = data` instead

Comment: error still persists

Answer (score 1):

In your code `comics_in_box` is a JSON string and not a `dict` object as you are dumping it already. You cannot expect to parse a string like a `dict`

I made some changes to correct your code.

```
response_API= requests.get('https://api.shortboxed.com/comics/v1/new')
# Use the JSON object as is
comics_in_box=response_API.json()
conn = pymysql.connect(host ="", user ="", password = "", db ="")
cursor=conn.cursor()

#The respons contains comics as the key to the array
for comic in comics_in_box.get("comics"):
    title=comic.get("title")
    publisher=comic.get("publisher")
    price=comic.get("price")
    diamond_id=comic.get("diamond_id")
    cursor.execute("insert into Shortbox (title, publisher, price, diamond_id) value (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (title, publisher, price, diamond_id))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the json directly to a pandas dataframe and write that to the server via to_sql method.

The dataframe will look like

[image]

Use the code as follows to load that df via sqlalchemy to the db

```
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

response_API= requests.get('https://api.shortboxed.com/comics/v1/new')
data = json.loads(response_API.content)
df = json_normalize(data, record_path=['comics'])
engine = create_engine("mysql://user:password@localhost:port/db")
df.to_sql(name='Shortbox', schema='dbo', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```